# I've overrode setHighlight in my custom UITableViewCell class. However, I don't always want to use it. How can I prevent from it being used?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm coloring my custom cell's in my custom uitableviewcell's -setHighlighted method. Works great.

However, I have some controller where I want to use this, and others where I don't want any highlighting at all.

Setting the cell's `.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` does not work when I have `setHighlight` overwritten.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UITableViewDelegate`s `-tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

U can try to check `self.selectionStyle` in setHighlighted and use super method if `self.selectionStyle == UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately it turns out I need 'None' on to use the custom setHighlighted override.

Comment: have u try to rewrite `- (void)layoutSubviews;` ?